# How to specify the path name in "-overview" option in Javadoc?

Tags: netbeans, javadoc

I'm having trouble specifying the path name for "-overview" option for Javadoc, using Netbeans IDE.

The file "overview.html" is located under the project directory: "~/NetBeansProjects/".

I've tried "overview.html", "src/overview.html" and "~/NetBeansProjects//src/overview.html".  They don't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to my own question.  I had to use the fully qualified path name under "Build" and "Documentation".  The entry for "Additional Javadoc Options" is:

> -overview /Users//NetBeansProjects//src/overview.html

FYI, I'm using NetBeans on Mac OS-X Mavericks.